# Detecting the last separator in a Data repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, separator

I am using a repeater (ASP.Net/C#) to show a list of names using a comma in the SeparatorTemplate. The problem is that I get a list that looks like this:

```
James, Bob, Joe, Frank
```

Whereas I would like to have something like:

```
James, Bob, Joe and Frank
```

How can I detect the last separator so that I can make it show " and " rather than ", "?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the markup of the Repeater? The ',' is something that is not the actual data but something you add?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can count items and display "and" instead of "," for the last item. To test I have this markup:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Container.DataItem %>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <SeparatorTemplate>
        <%# (Container.ItemIndex <((ArrayList)Repeater1.DataSource).Count  - 2?",":" and ") %>
    </SeparatorTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ArrayList values = new ArrayList();

        values.Add("James");
        values.Add("Bob");
        values.Add("Joe ");
        values.Add("Banana");
        values.Add("Frank");

        Repeater1.DataSource = values;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

And my output:

[image]

Comment: Hi afzalulh. Once again you save my day :). Sorry for not mentioning that my datasource was a datatable. Nevertheless, you provided me with the right solution. All I had to do was change one line to
 `<%# (Container.ItemIndex < ((System.Data.DataTable)rptLikers.DataSource).Rows.Count - 2 ? ", " : " and ")%>`
 and everything worked great. Thanks!